# Using C to reinterpret an array of u64, to 3D of u16 without changing memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management

I am very stumped, I have a pointer to an array of unsigned 64 bit integers. Each 64 bit integer actually represents 16 bit integers so that it should be split into a 16 bit array such that for instance:

36348941 should spit out as:

0,0,554,41997

However in C I can't see a methodology of performing this typecast. I understand C to have lots of potential with memory management, I would like it that I don't have to iterate through the data in order to perform this action but to simply change how the data is interpreted in memory, having the processor allocate and de-allocate memory will be time consuming for my program (it needs to run as fast as possible - preferably less than 20 milliseconds).

If I simply put:

```
arg1 = *(unsigned short (*))(&arg2);
```

I find the data has truncated the bits so spits out only one value per 64 bit integer which with the above case would be 41997.

This is only the first part of a further tricky issue to the application, next this array of 16 bit values need to be cast to a three dimensional array, while I can get this program to compile by doing:

```
const int I = 4;
const int J = 256;
const int K = 256;
arg1 = *(unsigned short (*)[I][J][K])(&arg2);
```

But this gives me no data, I have seen this work in other languages but they re-allocate memory which is thereby time consuming and preferably I would like all this to happen in the processor, no need for memory allocation as it is just requiring that the mapping of the bits in memory be different, not the data itself.

I then need to be able to pass this data back as a pointer to the three dimensional array. The reason for this is that the language I am working in to achieve this is doing as mentioned above, memory allocation but the overhead in calling a C DLL very minute so seems to have potential to be a solution.

I have also looked into Unions but I now understand that to be an incorrect way of using Unions.

I've not touched C in many years and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `arg2` defined?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, arg2 is defined as unsigned long* arg2 in the function prototype.

Comment: Be aware that long is only 4-bytes long on many 32-bit platforms. Also, the order of your indexes I, J, K will probably not agree with your intention - if you have a sequence of 64bit integers, you cannot index the 4 16-bit "planes" through first index of 3D array, but the last one. Finally, there is a problem with little-endianness and big-endianness, depending on a platform you run the code, the order of bytes will be different, giving different (sometimes incorrect) results.

Comment: Hag the memory `arg2` points to been allocated on the heap?

Comment: if `arg2` is a pointer then obviously anything involving `&arg2` is a mistake... it would help to show the declaration of `arg2` and how you allocated space for it to point to (and how you got data into that space)

Comment: Hi M.M Well this is a little bit of the tricky part also. LabVIEW is calling this C DLL (as I said, it seems the programming environment I am using likes to allocate new memory which I do not want) LabVIEW does have a reinterpret method but it does not work with multi-dimensional arrays and seems to think this is a transformation rather than reinterpretation.

Anyway, LabVIEW Calls this C function, with function prototype:

    void trying(uint16_t *arg1,uint64_t *arg2)

Nor does LabVIEW support returning multi-dimensional arrays so i'm having to pass two pointers. which makes it messy I guess

Comment: what do they point to? separate areas? If that is your prototype then why are you writing `arg1 = ` anything?

Comment: Yes I think this is where my pitfall lies, LabVIEW requires that the data is given in handles or pointers, that the data be given space before hand and then pointers given to the C Library hence my function prototype is in this fashion.

Thanks to everyone for providing a method in C to do this, it does work I have tested it and it is indeed as Unions which was one avenue I tried but another stack overflow post said that was wrong to type cast in such a fashion. My pitfall now is how this interacts with LabVIEW as memory management is very hidden from the user. I will research further..

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can't do this using a `uint16_t *` or anything like that. This is because of the *strict aliasing rule*: it's only permitted to access memory via an expression of some type, if the memory was originally written via that type  (with a short list of exceptions).

If you did want to do that you would also have to rely on compiler extensions to compile a C-like language but without the strict aliasing rule, e.g. gcc with the switch `-fno-strict-aliasing`.

The more portable way would be to use a union:

```
union U
{
    uint64_t a[10][10];
    uint16_t b[10][40];
};
```

Unions supersede the strict aliasing rule; you can write the data into `a` and read it out from `b`.

Of course, the order of the output will differ depending on platform.

Comment: If the "source" data (64bit array here) had been allocate on the heap using `malloc()` or friends it is guaranteed to be correctly aligned to any boundary, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but the strict aliasing rule is completely different to alignment considerations. I think it's safe to assume that `uint64_t` is correctly aligned for `uint16_t`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It just dawn to me myself ... thanks for reminding any ways! ;-)